# margin-top and margin-bottom for @media print in Safari

Tags: html, css, safari

I am working on a web application that essentially generates a formatted resume for any student that has their data stored in a reporting database (this data is pulled from a service call and populates the template). Because student data will be variable, every resume generated has potential to appear differently in where page breaks occur and how many pages will be generated, etc. As is the nature of a resume, the document needs to be printed.

I am having specific issues when printing from Safari with `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` not applying to different pages of the resume. To clarify, I only see these rules having affect on the first page's top margin and the last page's bottom margin respectively. This leads me to believe that Safari has no sense of setting margins by the page (`@page` has no support in Safari which would easily solve this issue), and is applying the margin properties to the entire `<div>` that I have the set the margin rules on (a class I have named "resume").

You can imagine the markup looks like so:

`<html>
    <body>
        <div class="resume">
            ...
        </div>
    </body>
</html>`

The above produces the results as expected in Chrome, even without using `@page` specifically - seems like Chrome is better with setting default margins, whereas I am struggling to find a solution in Safari.

More specifically, I have tried resetting all margins to `0` to let the browsers handle the margins on their own, but for some reason Safari reflects no margins at all whereas Chrome will instate ~1 inch margins by default.

Anyone have any ideas on how I could get margins to be respected on a page by page basis **when printing in Safari**? Or is this simply a nightmare to accomplish? Scouring the internet has not been too fruitful.

Please feel free to request additional information or lmk if anything is not clear. Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: which version of safari are you using? it's ok on all other browsers (IE 11, Edge, Chrome, Firefox..)?

Comment: "Or is this simply a nightmare to accomplish".
This has been my experience.